# Zeros as missing cases in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a csv with millions of cases that look like this:

```
Case_1,11,17481,172,4436,8,4436
Case_2,11,1221,680,55200,1776,55200
Case_3,16,6647,6449,579967,1,579967
Case_4,22,0,0,0,0,0
```

In this case, `Case_4` is missing data, since it has a bunch of zeros in it (there are hundreds of these in the file). I'm very new to R, and I was wondering if there is an efficient way of deleting these kinds of missing data from the file? Thanks.

Comment: Is there ever a case where 0 is actually a real data observation?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean exactly by "deleting these kinds of missing data from the file". What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `na.strings` argument when reading in your file.

```
df <- read.csv("filename.csv", na.strings="0")
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replace all your zeros with missing values than.

`x = data.frame(dataset)
 x[x==0] = NA`

Where dataset is the variable where you have saved the csv file

Comment: Do not use `NaN` to represent missing values in R. Use `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the rows which have 0 entries (as desired by OP):

```
ddf[ddf==0]=NA
ddf = ddf[complete.cases(ddf),]
```