# Certain pattern as missing data in R

Tags: r, missing-data

A dataframe consists of 5 variables:

```
> head(list_outdegrees, 5)
             Name OUTdegrees Followers Friends Statuses
1          Case_1         11     44423    4053    34518
2          Case_2         35         0       0        0
3          Case_3         13     41775     404   279384
4          Case_4         20     91952       0   108603
5          Case_5         13     31886    2885     4847
```

I've recently [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957742/zeros-as-missing-cases-in-r) on this site how to make zeros as missing in R, and was told to use `na.strings` as in `read.csv("filename.csv", na.strings="0")`. This works great, however this not exactly what I need, since sometimes zeros are actual data in my case.

In the example above, `Case_2` is missing data, because `Followers`, `Friends`, and `Statuses` variables are all zeros. In case of `Case_4`, however, zero is an actual piece of data.

So missing data is only when a case has the three variables (`Followers`, `Friends`, and `Statuses`) as zeros. Also, `OUTdegrees` always has a value regardless of whether its missing data or not.

Is it possible to tells R to delete (or disregard) cases when, and only when, `Followers`, `Friends`, and `Statuses` are all zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subset function:

```
subset(list_outdegrees,Followers!=0 | Friends!=0 | Statuses!=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to remove rows where one of the three zero's is actually a missing value. I would read the file in with the missing values, remove the missing rows, and then impute 0's manually.

```
data <- read.csv("filename.csv")
data <- data[!(is.na(data$Followers) & is.na(data$Friends) & is.na(data$Statuses)), ]
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowSums` on the logical index matrix of the concerned columns (`list_outdegrees[-(1:2)]!=0`).  This would be useful when there are multiple columns.

```
 list_outdegrees[!!rowSums(!!list_outdegrees[-(1:2)]),]
 #   Name OUTdegrees Followers Friends Statuses
 #1 Case_1         11     44423    4053    34518
 #3 Case_3         13     41775     404   279384
 #4 Case_4         20     91952       0   108603
 #5 Case_5         13     31886    2885     4847
```

The above can be also written as

```
 list_outdegrees[rowSums(list_outdegrees[-(1:2)]!=0)!=0,]
```

Or use `Reduce` with `|`

```
 list_outdegrees[Reduce(`|`, list_outdegrees[-(1:2)]),]
 #    Name OUTdegrees Followers Friends Statuses
 #1 Case_1         11     44423    4053    34518
 #3 Case_3         13     41775     404   279384
 #4 Case_4         20     91952       0   108603
 #5 Case_5         13     31886    2885     4847
```

#### data

```
list_outdegrees <- structure(list(Name = c("Case_1", "Case_2", "Case_3", "Case_4", 
"Case_5"), OUTdegrees = c(11L, 35L, 13L, 20L, 13L), Followers = c(44423L, 
0L, 41775L, 91952L, 31886L), Friends = c(4053L, 0L, 404L, 0L, 
2885L), Statuses = c(34518L, 0L, 279384L, 108603L, 4847L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"OUTdegrees", "Followers", "Friends", "Statuses"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```